# Authentication filter in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I created a simple custom authentication filter in Web API 2, which look like this.

```
public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string authToken = context.Request.Headers.GetValues("CustomAuthHeader").FirstOrDefault();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new UnauthorizedResult(new AuthenticationHeaderValue[0], context.Request); 
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

I have below question on this-

1). AuthenticateAsync is for implementing the core authentication logic but what is the use of ChallengeAsync in real life. If possible please explain with a example.

2). Why its returning Task. Will it create a new thread at back end every time (Wherever apply). If it create a new thread every time, when this thread will be killed?

3). What is the role of Task.FromResult(0)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. `ChallengeAsync` is used to add authentication challenges to the response, if needed. Typically it is used in case of 401 Unauthorized to provide information about authentication required by server.
2. Methods return task to support asynchronous execution and chaining.
3. Methods contain no really asynchronous methods that's why they return dummy already completed task to satisfy implemented interface.

I guess [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) should help you a lot.